# Javascript modification needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to check a class value for a certain string. The class could have multiple values separated by commas. The code needs to be modified so when West is selected everything goes away except the rows that have West included in the class value. Examples:

```
<tr class="West"></tr> (shows up)
<tr class="West,NE"></tr> (shows up)
<tr class="NE"></tr> (doesn't show)
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var links = $('#lb01'),
        regions = $('.West,.NE,.Southeast,.East,.South,.Central,.Northeast,.HO,.National,.US,.Texas,.Mid-Central');
    regions.not('.West').hide();
    links.change(function(event) {
        regions.hide().filter('.' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].id).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

html

```
<div class="tabset">

            <div id="tab1" class="tab-box">
                <div class="form-holder">
                    <form action="#">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="lb01"><strong>Choose District:</strong></label>
                            <select id="lb01">
                                <option class="bound" id="West">WEST</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="NE">NE</option>

                                <option class="bound" id="Southeast">SOUTHEAST</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="East">EAST</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="South">SOUTH</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="Central">CENTRAL</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="Northeast">NORTHEAST</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="HO">HO</option>

                                <option class="bound" id="US">US</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="Mid-Central">Mid-Central</option>
                                <option class="bound" id="Texas">Texas</option>
                            </select>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="report-box">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="name">Name</td>
                                <td class="department">Department</td>
                                <td class="title">Title</td>

                                <td class="district">District</td>
                                <td class="profile">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="West,NE,Southeast">
    <td>Name1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a class="btn-profile" href="#">PROFILE</a></td>
</tr><tr class="West">
    <td>Name2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 <td><a class="btn-profile" href="#">PROFILE</a></td>
</tr><tr class="East">
    <td>Name3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><a class="btn-profile" href="#">PROFILE</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: When an element has multiple classes, the class names must be separated by **spaces**, not commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't have commas in your `class` attribute. **Classes are space-delimited**:

```
<tr class="West NE"></tr>
```

Now, all you need to do is this in your `change` function:

```
links.change(function(event) {
    $('.report-box tr').hide().find('.' + this.value).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is going to be a big post.

**First of all**, you can condense the regions variable by just selecting the  elements, `var regions = $('tr', '#regions');` - This is clean, a standard coders try and stick to, and more efficient/dynamic. **Next**, the easiest way for class comparison is by overloading the classes, so you would have `class="West NE"` instead of `class="West,NE"` - this allows you to use the `jQuery.hasClass` function which is extremely useful.

Based on what I just said, I came up with the new code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var links = $('#lb01');
    var regions = $("tr","regions");

    links.bind("change",function(){
        regions.hide().hasClass(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use commas to separate your class names, for starters. That was probably the culprit if what you have isn't working.

---

Here's an alternate way of doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $links = $('#lb01');
    $(".report-box tbody tr").hide();

    $('tr.West').show();

    $links.change(function(event) {
        var region = $(this).find(":selected").attr("id");
        alert(region);
        $(".report-box tbody tr").hide();
        $(".report-box tbody tr." + region).show();
    });
});
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/thz99/